# Render React Components in DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I appreciate anyone's help! It seems to me I cannot find a solution to this problem. Here is my situation:

I currently have a sidebar and a top bar, navigation, in React. Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrxMk.png) of my app so far. I want to render components, essentially when clicked from the sidebar, in a targeted DOM. Here is my Sidebar component:

```
export default function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <nav id="sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar-header text-center">
          <h3>Point of Sales</h3>
          <strong>POS</strong>
        </div>
        <ul className="list-unstyled components">
          <li>
            <Link to="/inventory">
              <i className="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
              <span className="navText ml-3">Inventory</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i className="fas fa-image"></i>
              <span className="navText">Portfolio</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i className="fas fa-question"></i>
              <span className="navText">FAQ</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i className="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
              <span className="navText">Contact</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="content">
        <Topbar />
        {/* Render navigation components here!*/}
      </div>

      <Route path="/inventory" exact={true} component={InventoryView} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, now when I click on a link from the sidebar, it will render my component like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6lvG.png). I have already tried to do this with passing props, React composition,  to a custom component and rendering it there; however, it has not worked for me.

Any suggestions? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: so you have a parent `<div id="content">` to render navigation components as you state, but you declare your route outside of it?

Comment: This is not so much a react router issue as it is a "HTML structure + CSS" issue. And why does your sidebar component also contain the topbar *and* main content? And what do you mean by "targeted DOM"? Anyway, a `<Route>` component is basically a conditionally rendered component; whether it is rendered or not depends on whether its path matches the current route. This means it does need to be at the proper place inside your App's JSX, like any regular component.

Comment: Ok, i'm posting it as an answer to accept it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a `Route` that renders a component outside of the parent tag that you wish to do.
It should be like that.

```
  <div id="content">
    <Topbar />
    <Route path="/inventory" exact={true} component={InventoryView} />
  </div>
```